# How can I align centered <li> tags within a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, html-lists

I need to align text using li in a centered table so that the bullet points are aligned with each other. How can I do this?

```
<tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="selectedRecord" value="<%=objRS("P_PageID")%>" <%=CheckedByUser(objRS("P_PageID")) %>></td>                                    
                <td valign="top" align="left"><%=objRS("P_Description")%>&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign="middle" align="center">  
                <center><div style="text-align:left">          
            <%
                Page_ID = objRS("P_PageID")                        
                for i = 0 to (increment - 1)
                if testArray(0, i) = Page_ID then
                    %>                 
                    <li style="height:6px;"><%=testArray(1,i)%></li></br>
                    <%
                end if                        
                next   
            %>
            </div>
            </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It would help if you reduced the irrelevant Classic ASP out of the question, and made a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing the problem.

Comment: @thirtydot I only kept the classic asp in to show that the <li>'s were being looped

Comment: So how about a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) demo showing the problem? *Hint: it makes your question much easier to answer.*

Comment: You can't have list items outside of a list, start with [valid HTML](http://validator.w3.org/), then worry about styling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `<li>`'s in a div with a set width.  The div should be centered via your other CSS, then set the div to `text-align: left;`

Your list will be centered, because it'll be in the centered div, but the bullets/text will be left aligned within that div.  Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but the <li>'s are not centered within the <td> tags how can i fix this?

Comment: @kurupt_89 - Put the mentioned div within your <td></td> tags:   `<td><div><li></li>...more li's...</div></td>`